# Finding cumulative sum based on a condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cumulative-sum

I would like to implement the following in pandas data frame. I am unable to find a solution for this and would like your help.

---

INPUT

---

```
A  |  B | C
1  |100 |             
1  | 10 | 30           
1  | 20 |        
1  | 30 |
```

---

OUTPUT

---

```
A  |  B  | C            
1  | 100 |             
1  | 110 | 30            
1  | 100 | (110+20)-30        
1  | 130 |
```

Comment: Column A is ID and I would like a cumulative sum  for all the similar ID's

Comment: What is the meaning of 20 and why do you subtract 30?

Comment: @DYZ in the 3rd row you would add 20 to 110 because you want the cumsum of col B but you also subtract the 30 of col C

Comment: @DYZ (110+20)-30 is just the description of how column B  row 3 is derived. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @NishitMehra you could calculate the cumsum of col B and col C and then subtract B-C.

Comment: @luigigi Thanks mate but I want to implement this using python. Could you please help me with the code snippet? I want the similar output data frame as I have posted in the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any thinking, research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the cummulative sum of column 'B' by the id in column 'A', with substarction of column 'C' *before* that line, do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 100, 0], [1, 10, 30], [1, 20, 0], [1, 30, 0], [2, 15, 0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('A').cumsum()['B'] - df.groupby('A').shift().cumsum()['C'].fillna(0)
df
```

Output:

```
  A    B    C    cumsum
0 1  100    0     100.0 
1 1   10   30     110.0 
2 1   20    0     100.0 
3 1   30    0     130.0 
4 2   15    0      15.0
```